# Procedure for linked servers SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, union

I must to create stored procedure whit parameter for distributed database. I am work on SQL Server Management Studio Express. Procedure must be searching in distributed database with the use of operators like:

```
UNION
INTERSECT
EXCEPT
RPC
```

I've written a script but it doesn't work.

```
CREATE PROC UnioProccedure
   @Par_IDProdukt int,
   @Par_IDProducent int,
   @Par_Model char(20)
AS
   INSERT dbo.PRODUKT (IDProdukt, IDProducent, Model)
   VALUES (@Par_IDProdukt, @Par_IDProducent, @Par_Model)

   SELECT (
       SELECT * FROM PRODUKT 
       UNION
       SELECT * FROM [SERVERX].Shop.dbo.myTable
       WHERE 
          IDProdukt = @Par_IDProdukt and
          IDProducent = @Par_IDProducent AND
          Model = @Par_Model) a
GO
```

My second problem is :

create stored procedure for distributed transaction for two servers based on the protocol for 2PC.

I need only a schema.

Please help :)

Comment: By the way, two phase commit is for only UPDATES, INSERTS, or DELETES.  This is a SELECT statement.

Comment: Also, the same number of columns needs to be shown in a UNION which removes duplicates versus a UNION ALL.  Copy the table over to one server another database, get the SYNTAX right and then put on distributed system.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of linked server issues, your SELECT isn't structured correctly for the INSERT.  I don't see a reason to create a SUBQUERY either.  For clarity you ought to give names to your columns when using a UNION (UNION ALL is better performance).

Try this:

```
SELECT Col1 AS [ProdId],
       Col2 AS [IDProducent],
       Col3 AS [Model]
FROM PRODUKT AS P
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       Col1 AS [ProdId],
       Col2 AS [IDProducent],
       Col3 AS [Model]
FROM [SERVERX].Shop.dbo.myTable AS MT
WHERE 
  IDProdukt = @Par_IDProdukt and
  IDProducent = @Par_IDProducent AND
  Model = @Par_Model
```

Obviously I don't know what to call your columns but you need to give consistent names when using UNION ALL otherwise you have to refer to their position (1,2,3 ...) and that is ugly.

Make sure you change the WHERE clause and prefix the columns with the correct table alias.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read up on distributed transactions?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191156(v=sql.105).aspx

Did you read up on linked servers?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx

Please read and try yourself.  You will learn more than me giving you an answer ...

The key item is the have MSDTC running on both servers.